# Gritter Jquery script

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css

I have two questions regarding this [script](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/) :

1. How can i specify location to the pop up message (in specific div)
2. How can i pass parameters from c# to this script (Text for example/ c# datatable)

Comment: have you gone through the documentation (http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/)?$.extend($.gritter.options, { 
        position: 'bottom-left', // defaults to 'top-right' but can be 'bottom-left', 'bottom-right', 'top-left', 'top-right' (added in 1.7.1)

Comment: Sure Robert. I am using last version of the script. At this point it does not help me since i want to show this message inside some div.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have time to actually test it. But have you tried `$("#elementID").gritter.add({});` ?